PanelOLS - R Squared
I'm using the PanelOLS package in Python to estimate a fixed-effects model and have noticed that it provides four different R-squared values: rsquared_within, rsquared_between, rsquared_overall, and rsquared_inclusive. While I understand their interpretations based on the documentation, I've noticed that the literature typically reports the Adjusted R-squared for fixed-effects models. The definition of the rsquared_inclusive seems like the most generic one in terms of explained value using all the effects, but I am unsure if this has been adjusted.
Could you help me understand  which of these four measures corresponds to the Adjusted R-squared, or which is the most sensible to report in the paper?

With fixed-effects panel models, "within R-squared" is often reported because it reflects the variation within individuals over time, which is the primary focus of these models. This measure captures how much of the variation in the dependent variable is explained by the model, after removing individual-specific effects. Reporting the within R-squared is considered standard practice in econometrics literature (Baltagi & Li, 1995; Arellano & Bond, 1991). The within R-squared aligns with the purpose of fixed-effects models, which is to account for time-variant factors within each individual, subject, or entity.
That said, there are several R-squared values to consider in panel models, and it's helpful to understand their distinctions:
Within R-squared: This focuses on the variation within each individual or entity over time. It’s the most relevant measure for fixed-effects models as it captures the temporal changes within subjects after controlling for individual-specific effects.
Between R-squared: This measures the variation between individuals or entities, i.e., the cross-sectional variation across subjects. It's less relevant in fixed-effects models because these models primarily remove between-subject variation.
Overall R-squared: This is a more general measure, combining both within and between variation. While it might be useful for some comparisons, it is typically not the primary focus in fixed-effects models.
Inclusive R-squared: The rsquared_inclusive provided by the PanelOLS package appears to account for all effects in the model, but it is unclear from the documentation whether it adjusts for the number of predictors, as the Adjusted R-squared does. If you're interested in reporting an Adjusted R-squared, this may need to be calculated manually, as shown below.
Adjusted R-squared can be useful when accounting for the complexity of the model (Drukker, 2003). It adjusts for the number of predictors, penalizing the inclusion of variables that do not improve model performance, thereby preventing overfitting. While the within R-squared remains the primary focus in fixed-effects models, if you need an Adjusted R-squared, it can be computed manually using the following formula:
$$
R_{\text{adj}}^2 = 1 - \left( \frac{(1 - R_{\text{within}}^2)(N - 1)}{N - k - 1} \right)
$$
Where:

$ R_{\text{within}}^2 $ is the within R-squared,
$ N $ is the total number of observations, and
$ k $ is the number of time-varying predictors in the model, not including the fixed effects (entity-specific intercepts).

This formula adjusts the R-squared by penalizing the addition of predictors that do not significantly improve the model, providing a more accurate reflection of model performance, particularly in cases with many predictors (Drukker, 2003). Be sure to exclude fixed effects from the predictor count to avoid misinterpreting the degrees of freedom.
Although Adjusted R-squared is more commonly used in cross-sectional models, it can still be reported for fixed-effects models, particularly if there is concern about model complexity. However, keep in mind that in fixed-effects models, the Adjusted R-squared may not always be as informative, since the primary focus is typically on capturing within-individual variation over time, which the within R-squared already achieves.
In practice, most econometric papers report the within R-squared as the main goodness-of-fit measure for fixed-effects models, as this is directly related to the model’s purpose. The overall R-squared might be included for comparison, but it usually receives less emphasis since the interest is more on the temporal changes within each subject (Arellano & Bond, 1991).
If you need to report both R-squared values, including the Adjusted R-squared, make sure to clarify the purpose of each statistic in your analysis. While the within R-squared is typically the most relevant for fixed-effects models, the Adjusted R-squared provides an additional perspective on model fit, particularly when considering model complexity.
References:
Arellano, M., & Bond, S. (1991). Some tests of specification for panel data: Monte Carlo evidence and an application to employment equations. Review of Economic Studies, 58(2), 277-297. https://doi.org/10.2307/2297968
Baltagi, B. H., & Li, D. (1995). Testing AR(1) against MA(1) disturbances in an error component model. Journal of Econometrics, 68(1), 133-151. https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(94)01645-T
Drukker, D. M. (2003). Testing for serial correlation in linear panel-data models. Stata Journal, 3(2), 168-177. https://doi.org/10.1177/1536867X0300300206
